# how to use flink and spark together,and spark just for transformation?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-flink

Let`s say there is a collection "goods" in mongodb like this:

```
{name:"A",attr:["location":"us"],"eventTime":"2018-01-01"}
{name:"B",attr:["brand":"nike"],"eventTime":"2018-01-01"}
```

In the past,I use spark to flatten it and save to hive:

```
goodsDF.select($"name",explode($"attribute"))
```

But,now we need to handle incremental data,
for example,there are a new good in the third line in the next day

```
{name:"A",attr:["location":"us"],"eventTime":"2018-01-01"}
{name:"B",attr:["brand":"nike"],"eventTime":"2018-01-01"}
{name:"C",attr:["location":"uk"],"eventTime":"2018-02-01"}
```

some of our team think flink is better on streaming,because flink has event driver application,streaming pipeline and batch,but spark is just micro batch.

so we change to use flink,but there are a lot of code has been written by spark,for example,the "explode" above,so my question is:
Is it possible  to use flink to fetch source and save to the sink,but in the middle,use spark to transform the dataset?

If it is not possible,how about save it to a temporary sink,let`s say,some json files,and then spark read the files and transform and save to hive.But I am afraid this makes no sense,because for spark,It is also incremental data.Use flink then use spark is the same as use spark Structured Streaming directly.

Comment: "because flink has event driver application,streaming pipeline and batch,but spark is just micro batch" quite a blurry justification, i would say

Comment: @mangusta The point is the incremental data,our team leader says flink is better for it,but I am not sure and new to them

Comment: @nod - Please go ahead and read this - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It would help everyone to help you better.

Comment: @MontyPython sorry,I do not really get it,is it because I ask too many questions in one page,as: is flink better and how to use spark and flink together?Or I do not express it clearly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Apache Spark code can not be used in Flink without making changes in code. As these two are different processing frameworks and APIs provided by two and it's syntax are different from each other. Choice of framework should really be driven by the use case and not by generic statements like Flink is better than Spark. A framework may work great for your use case and it may perform poorly in other use case. By the way, Spark is not just micro batch. It has batch, streaming, graph, ML and other things. Since the complete use case is not mentioned in question, it would be hard to suggest which one is better for this scenario. But if your use case can afford sub-second latency then I would not waste my time in moving to another framework.

Also, if the things are dynamic and it is anticipated that processing framework may change in future it would be better to use something like apache beam which provides abstraction over most of the processing engines. Using apache beam processing APIs will give you flexibility to change underlying processing engine any time. Here is the link to read more about beam - https://beam.apache.org/.

Comment: Thank you.My complete use case is just incremental data:in my question,you could see we have 2 goods called A and B on 2018-01-01,after each another month.(maybe each week),we crawl more data from web,so we get goods "C" on 2018-02-01.Then we need to transform the new goods "C" from mongodb to hive.We can afford one hour latency.   And I guess flnk`s event driver is driven by trigger in mongodb,so mongodb push data to flink.I am new.